# Convert base64 format to pdf in java : output damaged file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am able to create a pdf file but when I try to open the output pdf file I am getting error : "the file is damaged"
Here is my code please help me.

```java
String  encodedBytes= "QmFzZTY0IGVuY29kaW5nIHNjaGVtZXMgYXJlIHVzZWQgd2hlbiBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YSBuZWVkcyB0byBiZSBzdG9yZWQgb3IgdHJhbnNmZXJyZWQgYXMgdGV4dHVhbCBkYXRh"; 

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);
File file = new File("C:/Users/istest/Documents/test.pdf");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(decodedBytes);
```

Comment: Can you share the error trace?
Also it doesn't look like you are trying to read file.. Looks like you are trying to write a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not a valid PDF file.
A pdf file should start its proper [Magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) (please refer to the ***Format indicators*** section of this link)

> PDF files start with "%PDF" (hex 25 50 44 46).

or in Base64 : `JVBERi`

if you try your code with a valid PDF encoded string like [this one](https://base64.guru/top/JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi-cxNA0KJSVFT0YNCg), it might work.

But because you did not provided the code of your `BASE64Decoder` class, it is hard to be sure that it will work.

For that reason, here is a simple implementation of the `java.util.Base64` package (Warning **do not** copy/past this example and **do not** try it before changing the given base64 string here with the correct one as supplied in the previous link...as noted in the bellow comment, in order to be short the correct string was replaced by a corrupted one)

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

class Base64DecodePdf {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("./test.pdf");

    try ( FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); ) {
      // To be short I use a corrupted PDF string, so make sure to use a valid one if you want to preview the PDF file
      String b64 = "JVBERi0xLjUKJYCBgoMKMSAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvRmlyc3QgMTQxL04gMjAvTGVuZ3==";
      byte[] decoder = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);

      fos.write(decoder);
      System.out.println("PDF File Saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Credit : [source](https://base64.guru/developers/java/examples/decode-pdf).

Comment: @DuraiD if it helped : you can accept it as valid answer...

Comment: Can you please provide end to end code to convert a string into pdf?